# Set user-interaction to false of a native Google Sign In Button

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

Is there a parameter userIntetaction in GIDSignInButton class? I want the button to become non-responsive after it is pressed once.

```
@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
```

I want to do something like -

```
signInButton.setUserInteraction = false
```

Comment: Try `signInButton.userInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GIDSignInButton` is a subclass of `UIControl`. Therefore it inherits the `isEnabled` property. Try setting this to `false`.

Also, as others have pointed out, you can also use the `userInteractionEnabled` field of `UIView`.

It would be better to use the `isEnabled` (first option) because that can show a different drawing for the `UIControl` subclass, if implemented.

Apple Doc for `isEnabled`

> Set the value of this property to true to enable the control or false to disable it. An enabled control is capable of responding to user interactions, whereas a disabled control ignores touch events and may draw itself differently.

Answer (score 0):

for disabling user interaction of any type of view in iOS, you can use this method:

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

this thing you can apply to GIDSignInButton too.